# Minus Opration in Crystal Report

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have total quantity of invoice and taken quantity, I want column in my report to display remaining quantity.
How can I do the minus values on remaining column, as in the picture

[image: This Picture]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you dont have any other column to tell how to deduct quantities day by day.

Comment: In Quantity column there is total (450) and in Taken quantity there is (100) I want display in Remaining column 450 - 100 = 350 and so on if take 50 is 350 - 50 = 300

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a Crystal CrossTab.
You can use the "Calculated Member" functionality of Crystal CrossTabs.

In the user manual, go to:
Cross-Tab Objects => Advanced Cross-Tab Features => Calculated Members.